# Using RegEx in View

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have a controller like this:

```
function Ctrl( $scope ){

    $scope.str = " Misty Mountain Hop ";

}
```

And a view like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <p>{{ str }}</p>       <!-- This one is ok -->
    <p>{{ str.split( "Mountain")[0] }}</p>   <!--Even this one is fine too -->
    <p>{{ str.replace( /Mountain/ , "Plain" ) }}</p>  <!-- This one is bad -->

</div>
```

So if i try to use a `replace` method , it gives an error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'Mountain' is unexpected ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H3ztj/

The question is : Why?

Comment: How can I reproduce that in the fiddle you linked to? Clicking "Run" doesn't produce any error, it just prints the code (unreplaced).

Comment: You can work around it by using the `RegExp` constructor: `str.replace(new RegExp('Mountain'), 'Plain')`. Note that there are no delimiters, you need to double all backslashes and modifiers go in a second parameter [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: BTW, why do you try to do this logic in HTML? I think HTML represents `View` (MVC) only

Comment: @TimPietzcker in the console you can see the error

Comment: @MaximShoustin i have very specific use-case with my view , so i don't want to put this functionality in the scope..

Comment: @m.buettner interesting idea , but still with no luck

Comment: actually `replace` works but not regex

Comment: @MaximShoustin i know , this works: `str.replace( "Mountain" , "Plain" )`

Comment: like I posted but removed after :). I prefer to use some basic directive and run it there, just the name will be different `myReplace="<regex>, <src>"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your question was "Why?", the answer is that expressions in interpolation blocks are not JavaScript expressions, but [Angular expressions](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression). They look a lot like JavaScript (on purpose), but Angular uses its own parser to parse the code.

That way it can do more than just evaluate the expression once: it can also do things like analyze the dependencies, so it can watch the ingredients and update when those ingredients change. It can also evaluate the expression relative to the `$scope`, so that `{{foo}}` returns `$scope.foo` rather than a global variable called `foo` (which in turn makes things like ngRepeat work).

When the Angular team implemented Angular expressions, they obviously didn't implement regular expressions. That's not surprising -- that kind of code should be in your controller anyway, where you can test it.

Comment: great , thanks! the reason it is not working is slashes in the  `replace(/Mountain/` , when this syntax is 100% works: `replace("Mountain"` , so seems like Angular team simply forgot to implement it :)