# How to replace multiple characters in angularjs view of an asp.net mvc

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have and angularjs view in html below

```
<tr ng-repeat="l in tutorRequests" class="form-text">
    <td>{{l.tutorid}}</td>
    <td>{{l.tutorsubject.replace(',',"")}}</td>
    <td>View Details</td>
```

the Output of the `<td>{{l.tutorsubject}}</td>` is in the format below:

Further Mathematics,Environmental Management,Geography
,Programming,Physics,

When I used `<td>{{l.tutorsubject.replace(',',"")}}</td>` it replaced the first comma in the output string. How can I replace all the comma character in the entire string? The idea is to replace the comma with a `</span><span class="">`

Would be waiting for your response.

Comment: See [Replacing all occurences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a regex with the global modifier `/,/g`:

```
<td>{{l.tutorsubject.replace(/,/g,"</span><span>")}}</td>
```

Or you can use the functional alternative:

```
<td>{{l.tutorsubject.split(",").join("</span><span>")}}</td>
```

**Note**: Setting `class=""` can be omitted because having no classes is the default.

Comment: There were errors when I used both codes however, when i replaces the `</span><span>` with another character, it worked. I guess it doesn't want html as the replacement string. How can I use html to replace the `,`?

Answer (score 3):

```
<td>{{l.tutorsubject.replace(/,/g,"</span><span class=''>")}}</td>
```

The regex `/,/g` matches all occurrence of comma in the string and replace with `</span><span class=''>`

Comment: Your code too didn't work either. I'm looking for how to fuse html as the replacement string.

Comment: what was your output? Did you get any error message? Was it something similar like `{{l.tutorsubject.replace(/,/g, '')}}`

Comment: It's not displaying anything at all however, when I used `<td>{{l.tutorsubject.split(",").join(" ")}}</td>`, I got result with space in between the subjects. I want the span html between the subjects so I can style it with padding, background color and margin to make the subjects look seprate and visually appealing.

Comment: Is it possible that you can evaluate the expression in angular controller file?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031157/angularjs-string-replace-in-html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208574/using-regex-in-view

Comment: Actually, the `{{l.tutorsubject.replace(/,/g, '')}}` is from the database along with other results. How do I evaluate it?